# Phonegap: Limit scrolling to Y axis only

Tags: css, cordova, scroll

I implemented a page slider in my phonegap app using 3d transform so its fast.

It looks great and works fine, but now i realize, that i can scroll the page in any direction, including left and right (x-axis).
But i need to prevent that somehow, is there any way, either Javascript/CSS or even ios/android to prevent the user from scrolling on the x-axis? Otherwise he can easily drag to the next screen.

I simply put a list of div's into a container and put them all to the right with the following CSS:

```
.page {
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  padding: 10px 10px 30px 10px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: .25s;
  transition-duration: .25s;
}
```

Then i use another class which simply resets the x transition back to 0%, so it slide from right to the left, while the current page slides from the center to the left with -100%.
But only scrolling by touchmove event is a problem here.

Any idea?

**UPDATE:**

Since it is still not working. To give more info. My HTML looks like this:

... 
   ...

You know the CSS from my page class. My container id has following rules:

```
#container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto !important;
  overflow-x: hidden !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following CSS:

```
body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden !important;
    overflow-y: scroll !important; //or auto
}
```

Comment: does not help. first screen is scrollable but if no more screens out of view on the right side it works. strange.

Comment: Updated answer. Added the !important tags to ensure it isnt overwritten further down. Make sure you put this in the body to so that it is at the top level.

Comment: this works on desktop browsers. but on mobile i have the touchmove event which seems not to be affected by the overflow setting, i can still scroll on both axis.